# Laravel upload image 'controlller'

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I'm following [this tutorial](https://w3path.com/laravel-6-image-upload-tutorial-example-from-scratch/) to image uploading in Laravel.

It says "After successfully creating controller, go to app/controllers/ImageController.php and put the below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator,Redirect,Response,File;

class ImageController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('image');
    }

    public function save()
    {
       request()->validate([
            'fileUpload' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
       ]);
       if ($files = $request->file('fileUpload')) {
           $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
           $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        }
        return Redirect::to("image")
        ->withSuccess('Great! Image has been successfully uploaded.');

    }
}
```

However, my code editor detects an error with the word `request` in this line

```
 if ($files = $request->file('fileUpload')) {
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Comment: No answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the variable `$request`, you need to inject it in the method as a parameter.

otherwise use the helper `request()` like you did for the validation.

```php
public function save()
{
   request()->validate([
       'fileUpload' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
   ]);
   if ($files = request()->file('fileUpload')) {
       $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
       $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
    }
    return Redirect::to("image")->withSuccess('Great! Image has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```

Using the variable `$request`

```php
public function save(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate([
       'fileUpload' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
   ]);
   if ($files = $request->file('fileUpload')) {
       $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
       $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
    }
    return Redirect::to("image")->withSuccess('Great! Image has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```

Comment: using "public function save(Request $request)" should be enough since the namespace is already added at the top of the controller.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi didn't notice it was already present in the controller. i put it in for precision. edited

Comment: I've done many, many photo upload tutorials over the last week and none work. Can anybody please point me to a simple tutorial which shows me exactly how to upload a photo to MySQL?

Comment: @PHP75DJ what's not working in your current code (except the path, remove the `public/` and use `$files->guessExtension()` to get the extention) ?

Comment: PHP75DJ, If this answer worked for you, accept it as the best answer, this way you will motivate @N69S him to answer more and more and consequently the community grows and becomes more responsive.

Comment: Currently nothing worked. I had a friend round yesterday who's been coding for 11 years and he said the tutorials I have been following are no good. He's going to install ImageMagick for me and then help me figure the photo upload system out. I appreciate everyone's help but I think my lack of knowledge is to blame here.

Comment: @PHP75DJ the file is not present at the location you set ? sure you did not save the path in the DB but the file must have been saved in `public/image/`. And `ImageMagick` is a tool to create and manipulate images, it has nothing to do with the upload part.

Comment: I think he wanted to install it before trying again, but I'll take a look - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you may have forgotten to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form
`<form action="{{url('dev/tester')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`